# Installing mysql-devel to match MySQL version

Tags: mysql, centos, yum

I'm running MySQL 5.1.52 on CentOS 4.6 and I'm trying to install mysql-devel to match my MySQL version. If I do yum install mysql-devel it wants to upgrade MySQL to 5.1.58, yet if I do yum search mysql-devel, in addition to finding 5.1.58, I get a match for: 5.1.52-jason.1 .. utterramblings .. Matched from: mysql-devel

Why is yum trying to install an updated version and is there any way to get it to install the correct version without the need to upgrade MySQL?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the mysql-devel package and version you need from a different repo.  Here's a couple to start:

http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/mysql-devel

Note you'll need to install using the rpm -i command, and it will expect you to already have various dependencies met.

Comment: I found a matching version at the pbone.net link, however the package is for CentOS 5. Would this install on 4.6? Also, is there any potential of causing problems with mysql itself if the system has any issues installing mysql-devel? That's my major concern. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As long as you're using the correct arch i.e. 32 or 64 bit, you'll be fine.  If it's the same version, the binaries should be compatible.  If you're concerned about things not working, you could always fall back to compiling it yourself, or switching to a distribution with better package management (I prefer ubuntu personally.)

Comment: I didn't realise you could install specific package versions via yum, I did a "yum install mysql-devel-5.1.52-jason.1.i386" and it installed fine.